# How to get the right date format in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I'm coding a web application using MEAN stack.
I need to save the date provided by mongoose to a record in node.js but the format of the saved string doesn't seem to be taken into account.

When I create a new record (named actualite), the .save() method calls moment() to format the pubDate that is correctly printed out by console.log("pubDate à sauvegarder vaut :", pubDate);.

However, it appears that this date format is not saved in data as shown by console.log("data à sauvegarder vaut :\n", data);

```
// Here is the model of actualite defined in node.js:

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ActualiteSchema = Schema({
    // Actualité
    title: String,
    description: String,
    // Image
    idImage: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Images' },
}, {
    timestamps: { createdAt: false, updatedAt: 'pubDate' },
    versionKey: false
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Actualites', ActualiteSchema);

// Here is the code used to create a new actualite

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Requête de validation
    if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: "Le contenu d'une actualité ne peut pas être vide !"
        });
    }

    // Créer une actualité
    var actualite = new Actualite({
        // Actualité
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        // Image
        idImage: req.body.idImage,
        pubDate: req.body.pubDate,
    });

    // Sauvegarder un produit dans la base de données
    actualite.save()
        .then(data => {
            pubDate = moment(actualite.pubDate, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ').format('ddd, D MMMM YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
            console.log("pubDate à sauvegarder vaut :", pubDate);

            console.log("data à sauvegarder vaut :\n", data);
            console.log("");
            res.send(data);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message || "Erreur lors de la création de l'actualité"
            });
        });
};

// This is the output generated by console.log():

pubDate à sauvegarder vaut : dim., 7 juillet 2019 19:55:52 +0200
data à sauvegarder vaut :
 { _id: 5d223228d8eb9525807e48cb,
  title: 'Test StackOverflow',
  description: 'this is a test',
  idImage: null,
  pubDate: 2019-07-07T17:55:52.532Z }
```

I expected that pubDate in data would be "dim., 7 juillet 2019 19:55:52 +0200" and not "2019-07-07T17:55:52.532Z"

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB stores the date in UTC, a universal way to represent time. If you wish to display a different format, you can either use `moment.format` (as you already used) or MongoDB aggregation `$dateToString`.

You won't be able to change the underlying representation of how Date is stored.